# How To find elements in html by condition using selenium in java?

Tags: java, selenium

I'm try to find two type of elements : td , img

and i tried using Xpath and cssSelector
as i want to find td , td/img  i use like this

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("td"))
```

and try

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[self::td|self::img]"))
```

but when using first one, i couldn't get img elements

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();  
    for(WebElement element : driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("td")))
    {
        if(element.getText().equals("img") == true) 
        {
            String tr = "img";
            list.add(tr);
        }
        else 
        {
            list.add(element.getText());            
        }
    }
```

and second one is not working well.

HTML code look like this.

```
<div id="bodyContent">
 <form name ="lessonForm" method="post">
  <div id="listBox">
   <div class="listContent">
    <dl class="element">
     <dd>
      <div class ="cont">
      <table class = "board">
       <thead> ... </thead>
        <tbody>
         <tr class ="odd-row">
            <td class ="first"></td>
            <td> offline </td>
            <td>  2022-03-02 </td>
        </tbody>
       </table>
      </div>
      :: after 
     </dd>
    </dl>
   </div>
  </div>
  
<div id="listBox">
   <div class="listContent">
    <dl class="element">
     <dd>
      <div class ="cont">
      <table class = "board">
       <thead> ... </thead>
        <tbody>
         <tr class ="odd-row">
            <td class ="first"></td>
            <td> offline </td>
            <td>  2022-03-09 </td>
            <td>   
                <img src ="on_full.gif">  
            </td>
              
        </tbody>
       </table>
      </div>
      :: after 
     </dd>
    </dl>
   </div>
  </div>
```

how can i add that img and td elements in List ?
It's just whether it's an img or not 
I wish I could bring a letter. to know what is this img.

I'm waiting for your help. Thank u for read this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whichever locator strategy you are using, be it CSS, xPath, etc. You should always make sure that these locators are unique in HTML-DOM.

**Steps to check if they are unique or not:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath/css` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

Also alone `td` is not a valid `CSS`, replace it with `//td` and make a valid xpath.

**Code:**

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();  
    for(WebElement element : driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td")))
    {
        if(element.findElements(By.xpath(".//img")).size() > 0) 
        {
            String tr = "img";
            list.add(tr);
        }
        else 
        {
            list.add(element.getText());            
        }
    }
```